# Asserting "enqueueAt" in my unit test on Hangfire's IBackGroundJobClient.Schedule<T> is failing and it shouldn't

Tags: unit-testing, datetime, moq, hangfire

I am using Hangfire for scheduling jobs. My code looks like this:

```
backgroundJob.Schedule<IDayBeforeRequestConfirmationMessageSender>(x => x.SendSms(requestIds, itinerary.Id), itinerary.Date.AddDays(-1));
```

my unit test (using MOQ), looks like this:

```
backgroundJobClient.Verify(x =>
            x.Create(It.Is<Job>(job =>
                job.Method.Name == nameof(IDayOfRequestConfirmationMessageSender.SendSms) &&
                job.Args[0] == requestIds &&
                (int)job.Args[1] == itinerary.Id),
            It.Is<ScheduledState>(ss => ss.EnqueueAt == itinerary.Date.AddDays(-1))), Times.Once);
```

this is the failure I'm getting:
"Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: x => x.Create(It.Is(job => (job.Method.Name == "SendSms" && job.Args[0] == ) && (Int32)job.Args[1] == 1), It.Is(ss => ss.EnqueueAt == 10/24/2016 12:00:00 PM))"

If I change the `It.Is<ScheduledState>(...)` call to `It.IsAny<ScheduledState>()`, the unit test passes.

I'm using the same code to set up the date in the code I'm testing with the date I'm setting up to expect in the test, **and they're the exact same value**.

So, does anyone know what Hangfire is really doing behind the scenes? After looking at the source code, I don't think I want to use `ss.ScheduledDate`, b/c that name is misleading... that captures the datetime the job was added to Hangfire. A scheduled job (like an enqueued job) ends up being added to the EnqueueAt property...

has anyone had this problem testing the IBackgroundJobClient's 
Schedule method before?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so ignore this question. It actually works. Sorry about that.